# how to add filter by price in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created a content type Products.
Its having price, ratings ,and other fields. And whenever I add a content for this product type it gives me submission date for that product. 
I have added 10 contents for this content type and created a view which displays all the products in a list. now i want to give a filter for "Price, Date and Ratings".

E.g, if I select price then it should sort the view list of product from lowest price to highest price value.

Any module is available to achieve this?? or any other procedure which can make this happen for product filter.

Comment: even i am trying to find out something related to this. Hope someone can help us regarding this.

Comment: Are you using drupal commerce, ubercart..??

Comment: Add the price field in the sort filter that's it !. Note: you have to add "Content: Product" under "Relationship".

Answer (score 2):

I have used Better Exposed Filters module in drupal for the same requirement. And i feel it will be very useful for you.

Just install the module from this link:
http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters

1. Enable the module. and Go to view(Create a new view and add your fields. For e.g, Price,Ratings,Date according your requirement. Else if you have already created a view then use the same and edit it.)
2. Click on Exposed form(In Advance) and select "Better Exposed Filters ".
3. Now select the filters you want in Sort Criteria(For e.g, Price,Ratings,Date).
4. Click on Use AJAX and select "yes"(Mandatory field).
5. Click on Save and Enjoy Your View with the Filter.

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the view and add a sort criteria for your field price there should be an option to expose it (tick box).

If you tick "Expose this sort to visitors, to allow them to change it" the sort filter will appear at the top of the view.

Comment: What version of views are you using or have you got an example where I can see this?